# Controle if posted api link started

Tags: php, api

I have application which post data to another site(running other application) with API link, and now I need returned feedback like "Application started!" or "error".. I tried to control variable `$result` but It returns me nothing. Application is started and everything works fine if I visit link with posted results.
If I visit API link manually, it just give me blank page(runned).

proces.php

```
<?php

if(isset($_POST['submit'])) {

  $ssId = $_POST['ssId'];
  $red = $_POST['red'];
  $id = $_POST['id'];
  $user = $_POST['user'];

$postdata = http_build_query(
    array(
        'ssId' => $ssId,
        'red' => $red,
        'id' => $id,
        'user' => $user
    )
);

$opts = array('http' =>
    array(
        'user'  => 'POST',
        'header'  => 'Content-type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded',
        'content' => $postdata
    )
);

$context  = stream_context_create($opts);

$result = file_get_contents('https://apiLink.com/someKey&ssId='.$ssId.'&red='.$red.'&id='.$id.'&user='.$user.'', false, $context);

header("Location: startApp.php");
}
?>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Problem is your current code handles request using `$_POST` however links trigger http `'GET'` method instead of `'POST'`, also you have some additional checks like `$_POST['submit']`, hence links redirect fails to work with your logic.

If you replace `$_POST` with `$_REQUEST` then things should work with links as well provided you send all the relevant parameters along with it. Other option is just give a button enclosed in form with hidden input fields.